# Visual Studio 2015 Remote iOS Build Server Setup - secure mode issue

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I am building a hybrid mobile app (Cordova) and I am trying to run my build on iOS.

I have followed the steps in this [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn757054.aspx#ios) to setup my connected Mac and I can see that the Mac terminal responding when I try to build my code in visual studio.

My issue is that when ever I enable the remote build server using `remotebuild --secure false` I get the following error in visual studio output(notice that the terminal is responding to the build request from visual studio but then fails with errors):

> Non-secure connection to http://192.168.1.10:3000/cordova could not be established. Verify that the build server is not running in secure mode.

And here is the Mac terminal activity with and output:

```
    Last login: Tue Aug 18 19:31:21 on ttys001
IBRAHIM-ALHUSSAINs-Mac-mini:~ IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN$ remotebuild --secure false
remotebuild
Copyright (C) 2014 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
1.0.1

Warning: No server modules selected. Defaulting to configuration "modules": {"taco-remote": { "mountPath": "cordova"} }
Build Retention initialized with baseBuildDir /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds, maxBuildsToKeep 20
Initialized BuildManager with baseBuildDir /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds; maxBuildsInQueue 10; deleteBuildsOnShutdown true; allowsEmulate true; nextBuildNumber 423
Remote build server listening on [http] port 3000
express deprecated req.host: Use req.hostname instead ../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/remotebuild/lib/server.js:257:81
GET /modules/taco-remote 200 14.494 ms - 7
New build request submitted:
/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=4.3.0&cfg=debug&loglevel=warn
{ 'accept-language': 'en-US',
  host: '192.168.1.10:3000',
  connection: 'close',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked' }
POST /cordova/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=4.3.0&cfg=debug&loglevel=warn - - ms - -
npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "taco-remote-multiplexer"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.4
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/.taco_home/node_modules/taco-remote-multiplexer/latest/npm-debug.log
```

I remember reading somewhere that I should enable secure build once then disable it in order to initialize the remote server security configuration. Whenever I try to run in secure build mode `remotebuild` I would get this error:

> Secure connection to https://192.168.1.10:3000/cordova could not be established. Verify that the build server is running in secure mode.

I have also attempted to resolve this issue by recreating PIN, generating and resetting the certificate.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: If you use --secure false, be sure to set "Secure Mode" to false in Visual Studio as well.  The PIN is only for secure mode so that will have no effect.  Drop to the command line on Windows and verify you can actually reach 192.168.1.10 by typing "ping 192.168.1.10" - given the error above, it sounds like you cannot.

Comment: @ChuckLantz Just updated my question with more output from the Mac terminal. I am able to do ping both ways and the remote build server response when I try to run my project from Visual Studio but it will still fail with the same errors mentioned above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the console output that you've included there, it looks like your mac can't access the npm repository:

```
npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
```

The line stating

```
New build request submitted
```

indicates that visual studio has successfully connected to the remotebuild server and has sent over a project to be built. As part of building a project, remotebuild dynamically acquires some npm packages to make sure that it is future proof and can work with multiple different versions of Cordova.

If you are unable or unwilling to let your mac see the npm repository, then it is possible to provide your own substitute function that determines what package to load to actually build the project.

I strongly recommend against doing this, but here is the simplest way to remove the functionality:

1. On a machine with access to npm, "npm install taco-remote-lib" to download the default package that performs cordova builds for remotebuild, then within that "npm install cordova@<version>" for the single version you intend to use. Open up taco-remote-lib/ios/iosBuild.js and replace

   TacoPackageLoader.lazyRequire("cordova", "cordova@" + cordovaVersion, buildInfo.logLevle).done(function pkg) {
       cordova = pkg;

with

```
cordova = require("cordova");
```

and remove the "}, function (err) { [...] })" at the end of the function you removed.

2. Copy the whole taco-remote-lib folder onto the mac, as it is now a self-contained instance which is specialised to a particular cordova version
3. Create a new js file somewhere "myRedirector.js", and give it contents similar to the following:

.

```
module.exports.getPackageToServeRequest = function (request) {
    return require("/path/to/copied/taco-remote-lib");
}
```

4. Create a configuration file that looks something like the following:

.

```
{
    "modules": {
        "taco-remote": {
            "requirePath": "taco-remote",
            "mountPath": "cordova",
            "redirector": "/path/to/myRedirector.js",
        }
    }
}
```

5. Start remotebuild by running "remotebuild --config path/to/the/config.json"

This should start remotebuild with a custom request redirector that uses your custom modified taco-remote-lib package to build all requests.

This will not respect the version of cordova that VS specifies for builds, since that requires the ability to download those versions from NPM on demand.

Comment: My Mac is not connected to the internet when I run `remotebuild --secure false` .. this seems to be the problem right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you run one build before disconnecting from the internet, it should cache the packages it needs (unless you use a different version of cordova that it needs to fetch) and it should work. It may invalidate its cache after a few hours though, but that is something we are fixing in the next version.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps because of  OS have Sandbox system

Comment: Please provide me with more detailed answer. Which OS are you referring to? Mac or Windows? How can I check and disable the Sandbox system?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had "'" in my mac's name. It did connect by host name once I removed "'".